# building library failed: file format not recognized; treating as linker script

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, linker

I use Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (gcc 7.4.0) I have successfully built [shaderc](https://github.com/google/shaderc) with all components required by [ktx library](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/KTX-Software). When I build ktx library (cmake/Iinux/debug or release) I get following errors:

```
[ 91%] Linking CXX executable gl3loadtests
/usr/bin/ld:/home/user/Downloads/KTX-Software-master/build/cmake/linux/Release/../../../../other_lib/linux/Release-x64/libSDL2-2.0.so: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:/home/user/Downloads/KTX-Software-master/build/cmake/linux/Release/../../../../other_lib/linux/Release-x64/libSDL2-2.0.so:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/gl3loadtests.dir/build.make:205: recipe for target 'gl3loadtests' failed
make[2]: *** [gl3loadtests] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:218: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/gl3loadtests.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gl3loadtests.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Symbolic links looks this way:

```
libSDL2-2.0.so -> libSDL2-2.0.so.0
libSDL2-2.0.so.0 -> libSDL2-2.0.so.0.9.0
libSDL2-2.0.so.0.9.0
```

Has anybody gotten the same errors on the linux ? How to fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the file size you will notice that the .so file is rather small, about 130 bytes. On the other hand, the repository holds a file of some megabytes in size (see [repository][1]). The discrepancy results from the way we downloaded the repository from the server: via *git clone*.

As hinted in the README, one needs the *git lfs* tool to read the repository correctly and completely. Unfortunately this seems not to run automatically, for whatever reason, but I found the following command sequence to help:

1. install **git lfs** from Ubuntu's standard software repository
2. remove the local repository completely and re-clone it (this might be unnecessary)
3. enter the directory containing the local repository clone
4. **git lfs fetch** (this might be unnecessary)
5. **git lfs pull**

The pull command finally replaces the small (about 130 bytes) files, that in fact are only lfs links to the repository, with their respective large binary files.

[1]: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/KTX-Software/blob/master/other_lib/linux/Debug-x64/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.9.0 : .so file in repository